# communication for ShinyModules for generating Rmarkdown report

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown

I have a fully functioning shiny, constructed of four different modules, in the first module, we upload the dataset we have, and in the second and third modules, we can plot based on the first module, and in the fourth module, we should be able to generate a report, connected to an rmd. file.
However I would like to render an HTML or PDF report from this, how can it be done? In an ordinary shiny we put the reactive function for the plots in the "report.Rmd" file and it will render the report.
However, it's not that easy with modules, what could be the solution, in order to generate reports based on several modules?
Thanks in advance!

```
file_upload_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabPanel(
    "Upload File",
    titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput(ns("file1"), "Choose CSV File",
                  accept = c(
                    "text/csv",
                    "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                    ".csv"
                  )
        ),
        tags$br(),
        checkboxInput(ns("header"), "Header", TRUE),
        radioButtons(
          ns("sep"),
          "Separator",
          c(
            Comma = ",",
            Semicolon = ";",
            Tab = "\t"
          ),
          ","
        ),
        radioButtons(
          ns("quote"),
          "Quote",
          c(
            None = "",
            "Double Quote" = '"',
            "Single Quote" = "'"
          ),
          '"'
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput(ns("contents"))
      )
    )
  )
}

file_upload_Server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      data <- reactive({
        req(input$file1)
        
        inFile <- input$file1
        
        df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath,
                       header = input$header, sep = input$sep,
                       quote = input$quote
        )
        return(df)
      })
      
      output$contents <- renderTable({
        data()
      })
      
      # return data
      data
    }
  )
}





first_page_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabPanel(
    "First Tab",
    titlePanel("My First Plot"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(ns("xcol"), "X Variable", ""),
      selectInput(ns("ycol"), "Y Variable", "", selected = "")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(ns("MyPlot"))
    )
  )
}


first_page_Server <- function(id, df) {
  stopifnot(is.reactive(df))
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      observeEvent(df(), {
        updateSelectInput(session,
                          inputId = "xcol", label = "X Variable",
                          choices = names(df()), selected = names(df())
        )
        updateSelectInput(session,
                          inputId = "ycol", label = "Y Variable",
                          choices = names(df()), selected = names(df())[2]
        )
      })
      
      
      graph_2 <- reactive({
        
        graph_w<- ggplot(df(), aes(.data[[input$xcol]], .data[[input$ycol]])) +
          geom_point()
        
        graph_w
        
        
      })
      
      output$MyPlot <- renderPlot({
        graph_2()
        
        
      })
      
      
      
      
    }
  )
}


mod_ggplot_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tabPanel("ggplot Tab",
           pageWithSidebar(
             headerPanel('My second Plot'),
             sidebarPanel(
               
               selectInput(ns('xcol_1'), 'X Variable', ""),
               selectInput(ns('ycol_1'), 'Y Variable', "", selected = ""),
               checkboxInput(ns("typeplotly"), "Use interactivity", FALSE)
               
             ),
             mainPanel(
               conditionalPanel(
                 ns = NS(id),
                 "input.typeplotly == true", plotlyOutput(ns("plotly"))),
               conditionalPanel(
                 ns = NS(id),
                 "input.typeplotly == false", plotOutput(ns("plot")))
               
             )
           )
           
           
  )
  
}


mod_ggplot_server <- function(id, df){
  stopifnot(is.reactive(df))
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    
    observeEvent(df(), {
      updateSelectInput(session,inputId = "xcol_1",label = "X Variable",choices = names(df()), selected = names(df())
                        
                        
      )
      updateSelectInput(session,inputId = "ycol_1",label = "y Variable",choices = names(df()), selected = names(df())[2])
      
    }
    
    )
    
    graph <- reactive({
      
      graph_res <- ggplot(df(), aes(.data[[input$xcol_1]], .data[[input$ycol_1]])) +
        geom_point()
      
      graph_res
      
      
    })
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      graph()
      
      
    })
    
    output$plotly <- renderPlotly({
      ggplotly(graph())
      
      
    })
    
    
  })
}

mod_Report_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tabPanel("Report ",
           mainPanel(
             width=12,title="Reporting information", solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",collapsible = F,
             # # Set title of report
             fluidRow(
               column(4,  HTML('Report title')),
               column(8,textInput(ns("title"), placeholder='Report title',label=NULL))
             ),
             fluidRow(
               column(4,  HTML('author')),
               column(8,textInput(ns("author"), placeholder='Modeler name',label=NULL))
             ),
             # Start report rendering
             fluidRow(
               hr(),
               column(6,radioButtons(ns('format'), 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'),
                                     inline = TRUE)),
               column(6,  downloadButton(ns("report"), "Generate report",width='100%'))
               
               
             )
             
             
             
           )
           
           
           
  )
  
  
  
  
}





mod_Report_server <- function(id){
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    
    
    
    
    output$report <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste('My_report', Sys.Date(), sep = '.', switch(
          input$format, PDF = 'pdf', HTML = 'html', Word = 'docx'
        ))
      },
      
      content = function(file) {
        src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')
        
        withProgress(message = 'Report generating in progress',
                     detail = 'This may take a while...', value = 0, {
                       for (i in 1:10) {
                         incProgress(1/10)
                         Sys.sleep(0.40)
                       }
                       
                     })
        
        
        
        
        owd <- setwd(tempdir())
        on.exit(setwd(owd))
        file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)
        
        
        
        library(rmarkdown)
        out <- render('report.Rmd', switch(
          input$format,
          PDF = pdf_document(), HTML = html_document(), Word = word_document()
        ))
        file.rename(out, file)
      }
    )
    
    
  })
}



library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(datasets)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Column Plot"),
  tabsetPanel(
    file_upload_UI("upload_file"),
    first_page_UI("first_page"),
    
    mod_ggplot_ui("ggplot_1"),
    
    mod_Report_ui("Report_1")
    
    
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  upload_data <- file_upload_Server("upload_file")
  
  first_page_Server("first_page", upload_data)
  
  mod_ggplot_server("ggplot_1",upload_data)
  
  mod_Report_server("Report_1")
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Rmarkdown file

---

### title: "`r input$title`"
author: "`r input$author`"
output: pdf_document

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
```

```
graph_2()
```

```
graph()
```

Comment: Your upload module has a return value, but your other three modules appear not to have.  if they did, then you could pass their output objects to the marrkdown document.  Wouldn't that solve your problem?

Comment: @Limey the return value for the upload module is the dataset "df", and the second and first module is based on it, in order to generate a plot. by "output projects" do you mean the "graph_2()" and "gragh()" that are being generated or how do you mean?

Comment: Yes.  Exactly that.  get your graphing modules both to *render* their plots in the UI and *return* the underlying ggplot objects to the main server.  The main server can then pass them to the markdown.  The simplest way to do this is to get the plot module to create a reactive `myPlot`, say, and render it in the module UI (`output$plot <- renderPlot({ myPlot() })`) *and* return `myPlot` from the server (`return(myPlot)`).

Comment: @Limey What you say, sounds definitely correct, however, when I did it, it just crashed the app..

Comment: Then, with all due respect, you didn't do it correctly.  We can't halep you with that part of your problem as you haven't shown us what you did.

Comment: @Limey I understand, Can you perhaps show me exactly where to put the reactive functions for the plots ("graph_2()" and "gragh()") and where to put "return(graph_2)" and "return(gragh)", would be much easier to understand

Comment: There are several posts of SO that show you how to do this.  See, for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69831550/shiny-modules-switch-tabs-from-within-modules-that-have-different-namespaces), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68584478/how-to-update-shiny-module-with-reactive-dataframe-from-another-module/68594560#68594560) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68584478/how-to-update-shiny-module-with-reactive-dataframe-from-another-module).  The Rstudio tutorial on modules is [here](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicate-bet-modules.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I came up with the solution. Now there is communication with all the modules and the rmd. file for rendering the report. Took some good time.

```
file_upload_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabPanel(
    "Upload File",
    titlePanel("Uploading Files"),
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput(ns("file1"), "Choose CSV File",
                  accept = c(
                    "text/csv",
                    "text/comma-separated-values,text/plain",
                    ".csv"
                  )
        ),
        tags$br(),
        checkboxInput(ns("header"), "Header", TRUE),
        radioButtons(
          ns("sep"),
          "Separator",
          c(
            Comma = ",",
            Semicolon = ";",
            Tab = "\t"
          ),
          ","
        ),
        radioButtons(
          ns("quote"),
          "Quote",
          c(
            None = "",
            "Double Quote" = '"',
            "Single Quote" = "'"
          ),
          '"'
        )
      ),
      mainPanel(
        tableOutput(ns("contents"))
      )
    )
  )
}

file_upload_Server <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      data <- reactive({
        req(input$file1)
        
        inFile <- input$file1
        
        df <- read.csv(inFile$datapath,
                       header = input$header, sep = input$sep,
                       quote = input$quote
        )
        return(df)
      })
      
      output$contents <- renderTable({
        data()
      })
      
      # return data
      data
    }
  )
}





first_page_UI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tabPanel(
    "First Tab",
    titlePanel("My First Plot"),
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(ns("xcol"), "X Variable", ""),
      selectInput(ns("ycol"), "Y Variable", "", selected = "")
    ),
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput(ns("MyPlot"))
    )
  )
}


first_page_Server <- function(id, df) {
  stopifnot(is.reactive(df))
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      observeEvent(df(), {
        updateSelectInput(session,
                          inputId = "xcol", label = "X Variable",
                          choices = names(df()), selected = names(df())
        )
        updateSelectInput(session,
                          inputId = "ycol", label = "Y Variable",
                          choices = names(df()), selected = names(df())[2]
        )
      })
      
      
      graph_2 <- reactive({
        
        graph_w<- ggplot(df(), aes(.data[[input$xcol]], .data[[input$ycol]])) +
          geom_point()
        
        graph_w
        
        
      })
      
      output$MyPlot <- renderPlot({
        graph_2()
        
        
      })
      
      return(graph_2)
      
      
    }
  )
}


mod_ggplot_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tabPanel("ggplot Tab",
           pageWithSidebar(
             headerPanel('My second Plot'),
             sidebarPanel(
               
               selectInput(ns('xcol_1'), 'X Variable', ""),
               selectInput(ns('ycol_1'), 'Y Variable', "", selected = ""),
               checkboxInput(ns("typeplotly"), "Use interactivity", FALSE)
               
             ),
             mainPanel(
               conditionalPanel(
                 ns = NS(id),
                 "input.typeplotly == true", plotlyOutput(ns("plotly"))),
               conditionalPanel(
                 ns = NS(id),
                 "input.typeplotly == false", plotOutput(ns("plot")))
               
             )
           )
           
           
  )
  
}


mod_ggplot_server <- function(id, df){
  stopifnot(is.reactive(df))
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    
    observeEvent(df(), {
      updateSelectInput(session,inputId = "xcol_1",label = "X Variable",choices = names(df()), selected = names(df())
                        
                        
      )
      updateSelectInput(session,inputId = "ycol_1",label = "y Variable",choices = names(df()), selected = names(df())[2])
      
    }
    
    )
    
    graph <- reactive({
      
      graph_res <- ggplot(df(), aes(.data[[input$xcol_1]], .data[[input$ycol_1]])) +
        geom_point()
      
      graph_res
      
      
    })
    
    output$plot <- renderPlot({
      graph()
      
      
    })
    
    output$plotly <- renderPlotly({
      ggplotly(graph())
      
      
    })
    
    return(graph)
    
    
    
  })
}

mod_Report_ui <- function(id){
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tabPanel("Report ",
           mainPanel(
             width=12,title="Reporting information", solidHeader = TRUE, status = "primary",collapsible = F,
             # # Set title of report
             fluidRow(
               column(4,  HTML('Report title')),
               column(8,textInput(ns("title"), placeholder='Report title',label=NULL))
             ),
             fluidRow(
               column(4,  HTML('author')),
               column(8,textInput(ns("author"), placeholder='Modeler name',label=NULL))
             ),
             # Start report rendering
             fluidRow(
               hr(),
               column(6,radioButtons(ns('format'), 'Document format', c('PDF', 'HTML', 'Word'),
                                     inline = TRUE)),
               column(6,  downloadButton(ns("report"), "Generate report",width='100%'))
               
               
             )
             
             
             
           )
           
           
           
  )
  
  
  
  
}





mod_Report_server <- function(id, graph_2, graph){
  stopifnot(is.reactive(graph_2))
  stopifnot(is.reactive(graph))
  
  
  moduleServer( id, function(input, output, session){
    ns <- session$ns
    
    
    
    
    output$report <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste('My_report', Sys.Date(), sep = '.', switch(
          input$format, PDF = 'pdf', HTML = 'html', Word = 'docx'
        ))
      },
      
      content = function(file) {
        src <- normalizePath('report.Rmd')
        
        withProgress(message = 'Report generating in progress',
                     detail = 'This may take a while...', value = 0, {
                       for (i in 1:10) {
                         incProgress(1/10)
                         Sys.sleep(0.40)
                       }
                       
                     })
        
        
        # Set up parameters to pass to Rmd document
        params_for_rmd =  list(plot_1=graph_2(),
                               plot_2=graph(),
                               set_title=input$title,
                               set_author=input$author)
        
        
        
        
        owd <- setwd(tempdir())
        on.exit(setwd(owd))
        file.copy(src, 'report.Rmd', overwrite = TRUE)
        
        
        
        library(rmarkdown)
        out <- render('report.Rmd', switch(
          input$format,
          PDF = pdf_document(), HTML = html_document(), Word = word_document()
        ))
        file.rename(out, file)
      }
    )
    
    
  })
}


















library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(plotly)
library(datasets)

ui <- shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Column Plot"),
  tabsetPanel(
    file_upload_UI("upload_file"),
    first_page_UI("first_page"),
    
    mod_ggplot_ui("ggplot_1"),
    
    mod_Report_ui("Report_1")
    
    
  )
))

server <- shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  
  upload_data <- file_upload_Server("upload_file")
  
  gplot_1 <- first_page_Server("first_page", upload_data)
  
  gplot_2 <- mod_ggplot_server("ggplot_1",upload_data)
  
  mod_Report_server("Report_1",graph_2 =gplot_1, graph = gplot_2)
  
})

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

the rmd. file

````
---
output: pdf_document
params:
  plot_1: NA
  plot_2: NA
  set_title: 
  set_author: 
title: "`r input$title`" 
author: "`r input$author`"

---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
library(ggplot2)
library(shiny)
library(rmarkdown)
library(knitr)
````

## my first plot

```
graph_2()
params$plot_1
```

## my second plot

```
graph()
params$plot_2
```

Comment: Hi @EnriqueGG, thanks for the solution. Could you please explain a bit what does `graph_2 =gplot_1, graph = gplot_2`mean in `mod_Report_server("Report_1",graph_2 =gplot_1, graph = gplot_2)`?